# Computing the Jacobian of an anonymous function - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, ode

I'm trying to solve a system of non linear odes in Matlab as follows.

```
editparams %parameters
Tend = 50;
Nt = 100;


% Define RHS functions

RHS = @(t,x) ModelRHS(t,x,param); %anonymous function defining the set of equations

%Execution-----------------------------------------------------------------
x0 =[0.04;0.75;0.85]; %Initial condition

t = linspace(0,Tend,Nt); %TSPAN
[t x] = ode45(RHS, t, x0);
```

Now, I need to find the steady state of the system and I'm trying to create a function for this. I thought I'd calculate the steady state using the Jacobian. My equations are in an anonymous function which is defined as `f` in the code below. However, I realised that `jacobian` does not work for anonymous functions (or may be there is a way to do with anonymous functions) . so I thought I would convert the anonymous function to a symbolic function and try it. But
i still have a difficulty in getting that done. So any help is really appreciated!

```
function SS = SteadyState(param, E)

f = @(t,x)ModelRHS(t,x,param,E); %set of odes

SymbolicSystem = sym(f); %trying to make the anonymous function symbolic

SymbolicJacobian = jacobian(SymbolicSystem',x); %jacobian 
Jacob = matlabFunction(SymbolicJacobian,x);

end
```

Also if there is any other way apart from finding the Jacobian, kindly let me know about that too.
I tried using 'fsolve' to calculate the steady-state as follows:

```
f = @(t,x)ModelRHS(t,x,param);
x0 =[0.04;0.75;0.85]';

options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter'); % Option to display output
SS = fsolve(f,x0,options); % Call solver
```

but it returned an error

```
    Not enough input arguments.

Error in @(t,x)ModelRHS(t,x,param)

Error in fsolve (line 242)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

Comment: What is `ModelRHS`? In general, you cannot convert a numeric expression to a symbolic one, you should start with a symbolic expression if you want to do symbolic math. If you only have a numeric function, you need to use numeric algorithms. There are numeric optimization algorithms that will find the steady state for you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your comment. `ModelRHS` is the function that defines all the odes in the model. Is there a way that I can use anonymous functions to find the steady state?